# python subprocess32 with timeout, overflowerror

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

this is my log

```
File "/opt/ibm/db2-governor/helpers/utils.py", line 10, in run_cmd
output = proc.communicate(timeout = timeout)[0]
  File "/opt/ibm/dynamite/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 927, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/opt/ibm/dynamite/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1713, in _communicate
    orig_timeout)
  File "/opt/ibm/dynamite/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1786, in _communicate_with_poll
    ready = poller.poll(self._remaining_time(endtime))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C lon
```

so the code that triggers this is

```
output = proc.communicate(timeout = timeout)[0]
```

timeout is set to 20, this happens intermitently (almost never but it happens), im using python 2.7.11 with subprocess32 library, is this a python bug?

ok, i checked subprocess32.py, the line goes like this

```
endtime = time.time() + timeout

ready = poller.poll(self._remaining_time(endtime))
```

so basically timestamp is too large to convert into a c int, is there anything i can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug all right.

If you're interested, here's a workaround proposal: instead of `communicate`, read from process `stdout` in a thread and check if process is over by either nothing more to read or return code yield through `poll`.

Since you control the loop, you can wait 1 second in main thread and countdown for the timeout (not extra accurate, since `sleep` can drift, but that would be good enough & simple). Also kill the process when reaches 0.

```
import threading

output = ""

def subp(p):
    global output

    while True:
        # read blocks but since we're in a thread it doesn't matter
        data = proc.stdout.read()
        if not data or proc.poll() != None:
            break
        output += data

# here create the process    
proc = subprocess...

# create a thread, pass the process handle
t = threading.Thread(target=subp,args=(proc,))

while True:
    if proc.poll() != None:
      # exit: OK
      break
    timeout -= 1
    if timeout < 0:
        # took too long: kill
        proc.terminate()
        break
    time.sleep(1)

t.join()
```

Comment: "if not data or proc.poll() != None:" should just be "if not proc.poll()?"

Comment: common trap: `proc.poll()` can return the return code, which can be 0. So it could not end. But I think my solution is incorrect: `read` is blocking. So timeout would have no effect. Let me edit.

Comment: concept is correct and i accept the concept by accepting the answer, code i have to rewrite anyways so i dont know D=

Comment: I guarantee that subprocess in a thread combination + supervising polling loop in the mainloop is a winner. Used that many times in tricky parallel coding situations. I shivered when I realized that my old answer was soooo wrong and yet you accepted it. Anyway, fixed now, won't keep me flom sleeping :)